# Polynomial roots

Tags: r, matlab

I have a small issue with a polynomial:

```
z²+alpha1*z + alpha2 = 0
```

I need to fins the values of alpha1 and alpha2 wihtin the roots of |z| < 1. Is there any program in R or Matlab able to do it?
the thing is that the alpha values are not known. I need to find the allowed area where the roots of the polynomial are <= |1|

Comment: Can't you do this analytically? You don't need to do this numerically I think...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@Jonel_R, your problem can be solved analytically.

First I'll rename your variables to make it easier to type. I'll also use some notation abuse...

We want to find the values `(a, b)` such that the roots of `z^2 + a z + b == 0` satisfy the property `|z|<=1`.

The roots are given by `(-a +- sqrt(d))/2`, where `d = a^2 - 4b`

There are 3 possibilities. Two real distinct roots, one real root or two complex conjugate roots.

The middle case happens when `d = 0`, i. e., `b = a^2 / 4`. This is a parabola in the `a vs. b` plane. Not all points in this parabola generate polynomials whose root satisfy `|z|<=1`, however. The root, is this case, is simply `-a/2`, so we mus add the condition `-1 <= a/2 <=1`, i. e., `-2 <= a <= 2`.

Now let's consider the first case. The points in the `a vs. b` plae that generate polynomials with two distinct real roots lie *below* the parabola, i. e., they must satisfy `b < a^2/4`. The additional condition is that `|z| = |(-a +- sqrt(d))/2| <= 1`.

The condition can be written as `-1 <= (-a +- sqrt(d))/2 <= 1`, where `+-` means both roots must satisfy the condition. Working this out we get:
`a-2 <= sqrt(d) <= a+2` & `a-2 <= -sqrt(d) <= a+2`

Since both `sqrt(d)` and `-sqrt(d)` must lie in the interval `[a-2, a+2]`, and `d > 0`, then this interval must contain zero in its interior. This means `-2 < a < 2`.

The conditions can be joined as:
`a-2 <= -sqrt(d) < 0 < sqrt(d) <= a+2`

Squaring gives:
`(a-2)^2 >= d` & `d <= (a+2)^2`

`d <=  a^2 - 4a + 4` & `d <= a^2 + 4a + 4`

`-4b <= -4a + 4` & `-4b <= +4a + 4`

`b >= a-1` & `b >= -a-1`

This means that `b` must be located above the lines `b = a-1` and `b=-a-1`. Also, `a` must be in `[-2,2]`. And, of course, we must have `b < a^2/4`. Wow...

Now the last case: complex roots. This is easier. Since `d < 0`, the roots are `-a/2 +- i * sqrt(-d)/2`. The absolute value of this is `a^2/4 - d/4`. This equals `b`, simply. So the condition is `b <= 1`, and, as always, `b` lying above that parabola.

That's it... Quite interesting problem. :-)

You can try the following test function: It'll plot the points with real roots in blue and complex roots in red.

```
test <- function(x=2, n=10000)
{
    plot(c(-x,x), c(-x,x), type="n")

    plot(function(a) (a^2)/4, from=-x, to=x, add=T)

    plot(function(a) a-1, from=-x, to=x, add=T)

    plot(function(a) -a-1, from=-x, to=x, add=T)

    a <- runif(n, -x, x)

    b <- runif(n, -x, x)

    for( i in 1:n )
    {
        if( all(abs(polyroot(c(b[i],a[i],1))) <= 1) )
        {
            col <- ifelse(b[i] < 0.25*a[i]^2, "blue", "red")

            points(a[i], b[i], pch=".", col=col)
        }
    }
}
```

BTW: the syntax for `polyroot` is `polyroot(c(C, B, A))` gives the roots of `Ax^2 + Bx + C`. I believe @agstudy response got it wrong.

Comment: Thanks for your help! I just mistook before with the polyroot() syntax. I had already done it analytically but I wanted an efficient way to implement it in R!! Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Similar to matlab solution in R ,

```
  polyroot(c(1,alpha1,alpha2))
```

**EDIT** here a method to get the values of `alpha` graphically, it can be used to get intution about the plausible values. The idea here is :

- choose a range of aplha1
- choose a range of alpha2
- for each combination of alpha1 and alpha2, compute the roots. Compute the module (||), if > 1 we remove it.
- we get a grid of values with 4 column: alpha1,alpha2,norm1,norm2 where All the norms are <1
- I plot alpha1 versus alpha2 to get regions...

So the code

```
## I choose alpha1 in interavl [-1,1]
alpha1 <- seq(-1, 1, length=200)
## I choose alpha2 in interavl [-2,2]
alpha2 <- seq(-2, 2, length=200)
dat <- expand.grid(data.frame(alpha1,alpha2))
## for each combination of (alpha1,alpha2)
## i compute the module of the roots 
## I replace |roots|> 1 by NA
ll <- apply(dat,1,function(x) {
  rr =Mod(polyroot(c(1,x['alpha1'],x['alpha2'])))
  res <- ifelse(rr>1,NA,rr)
  if (length(res)==1) res <- rep(res,2)
  if (length(res)==0) res <- rep(NA,2)
  else res
  })
dat <- na.omit(cbind(dat,t(ll)))
## finally i plot the result
library(lattice)
xyplot(alpha2~alpha1,data=dat)
```

[image]

Comment: But the problem is that I do not know alpha values.

Comment: @Jonel_R do you konw the limits at least?

Comment: I need the area wihtin the values alpha1 and alpha2 provide me a root (|z| <=1). So, I need that the complex roots lie inside a unit circle.

Comment: Great help! Thank you for your effort. Concerning the code can you explain me what exactly do you do in

    res <- ifelse(rr>1,NA,rr)
    if (length(res)==1) res <- rep(res,2)
    if (length(res)==0) res <- rep(NA,2)
    else res

Comment: Sorry for that, I understand everything except: 
if (length(res)==1) res <- rep(res,2)
When is it going to happen?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/26247/discussion-between-agstudy-and-jonel-r)

Comment: @agstudy, I believe you mean `c(x['alpha2'],x['alpha1'],1)`... Se my answer below.

Answer (score 0):

In matlab:

```
roots(1,alpha1,alpha2)
```

see http://www.mathworks.se/help/matlab/ref/roots.html

Comment: But the problem is that I do not know alpha values

Comment: oh, my bad, was too quick there